# Jquery conflicting with css last child

Tags: jquery, css

Right now i have a log list of reviews and I am currently toggling this list to show more reviews or hide some.

Before I put in this jquery to show/hide some of the list i had a some css for the class `.review` wrap that was `:last-child { border: none; }`, which was working until i put in this jquery.

My question is why all of sudden is this css selector not working in my style sheet when i implemented this jquery? I also tried just to do the last child in the jquery put it didnt work there either.

```
function reviewlistCutoff() {
    var hiddenReviews = $('.reviewWrap:gt(6)').hide();

    if (hiddenReviews.size() > 0) {
        var showCaption = '...' + hiddenReviews.size() + ' More Reviews';
        $('.reviewsList').append(
        $('<span class="toggler">' + showCaption + '</span>').toggle(

        function () {
            hiddenReviews.show();
            $(this).text('...Fewer Reviews');

        }, function () {
            hiddenReviews.hide();
            $(this).text(showCaption);
        }));

    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I think the answer lies more in your HTML and CSS; it's possible jQuery has added some class names, which have resulted in other CSS rules with higher specificity to affect these elements... can you create a demo of your problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: now for some odd reason my jquery isnt working in that fiddle but it works on my site, but the fiddle is set up

Comment: The CSS selector seems to work fine. I changed it to 3px red here, to make it clear that it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/TJctn/4/

Comment: Ok, now i got the jquery to work, now it shows that the last-child selector in the css isnt working   http://jsfiddle.net/TJctn/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.reviewWrap:last-child` is working fine.

The problem is that you're hiding the last 5 or so `.reviewWraps` - and the very last one is what `:last-child` is selecting.

What you actually want is to remove the `border-bottom` from the *last visible* `.reviewWraps`.

Fortunately though, there's a better way to solve this.

You can switch to using `border-top` and `:first-child` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/TJctn/6/

```
.reviewWrap { border-top: 1px solid #C9C9C9; margin: 0 0 20px; padding: 0 0 20px; }      
.reviewWrap:first-child { border-top: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Your first `.reviewWraps` will have the `border-top` removed.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do with your `margin` and `padding`, but you should be able to tweak them to perfection.

Comment: thats is a work around but its very odd , bc when i show all of them when i click the toggle all of them are showing so it should hit the last child

Comment: When you append the `<span class="toggler">` to the end of `.reviewList`, there is no matching element for `.reviewWrap:last-child` to select any more - the `:last-child` is not a `.reviewWrap`. Here's a simplified version with no jQuery showing the problem: [http://jsfiddle.net/TJctn/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/TJctn/7/). Switching to `:first-child` is definitely what you should do here.

Comment: (not relevant to the problem, but I had to fix `$('.reviewsList').append` to `$('.reviewList').append` to get the toggler to show up)